# react-native-map marker images source from a state

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

i have a state like this:

```
this.state = {
        width :  Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height :  Dimensions.get('window').height,
        initialPosition:  {
          latitiude: 48.866667,
          longitude: 2.333333,
          latitudeDelta:LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        },
        markerIcons: {},
        markers: [],
    };
```

In markerIcon i have different .png like this:

[image]

An din markers i have another object where appears different information and categories of traders :

[image]

I define my Markers as this in my render:

```
  {Object.keys(this.state.markers).map((marker, key) => (
          <Marker
              key={key}
              coordinate={this.state.markers[marker].coordinate}
              title={this.state.markers[marker].title}
              description={this.state.markers[marker].address}
              image={......}
          />
        ))}   
          </MapView>
        </View>
```

I would like the source of my images to match the categories of my traders.
The names are the same in both objects but how do I do it in my marker??
How can can i set my image source of my marker ??

thanks for your help ;)

Comment: didn't get you, can u explain little more ?

Comment: sure ,;) I would like to match the category in my state **"Markers.category"** with the image in my state **"MarkerIcon.icon"** and fill the source of my image with the right icon of the shot

Comment: so as per my understanding , if you have name like "barcofee" then your image name should be "barcofee.png" , right ?

Comment: yes right and the .png is in the second object

Comment: can you tried like this 
<Image
   style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
   source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAE'}}
        />

where iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAE is base64 stored as string in your array.

Comment: thx for your help ;)  ,  the second solution below works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the object of the `marker icon` like this

Assuming that your *marker icon object* is stored in `MarkerIcon`

```
this.state.markerIcons[this.state.markers[marker].category]
```

This will give you the object `{icon: '', label: ''}` for the same

Comment: yes but they are not in the same object , there are in two diff part of my state

Comment: `MarkerIcon` is a different object compared to `this.state.markers`, replace `MarkerIcon` with whatever object you have and you'll get the result or you can update the  question representing the states

Comment: I edited my post ;)  
I can access my icon in **markerIcon** but how do I set the source image by linking the two parts of my state? (in my render)

Comment: Try the above, to get the icons you can do `this.state. markerIcons[this.state.markers[marker].category].icons` similar to object

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom icon this way
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: please try to give relevant little more code which can be helpful ?